# Javascript - Find first occurence of either variable

Tags: jquery, selector

I spent an hour looking for it with no luck...
I need to run a `nextUntil()` in jQuery. Basically I wish to say:
whether it's `var1` or `var2` that jQuery finds first, `nextUntil(suchvar);`

I tried assigning this way but no success:

```
var either = var1 || var2;
...nextUntil(either);
```

ps:I omitted the rest of the code for sake of simplicity.

Comment: If you look at the value of `either` after that first assignment you will find that it will be `var1` if `var1` is "truthy" otherwise it will be `var2` if `var2` is truthy otherwise it will just be false. In any case, it will *not* capture the relationship you're seeking (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: So it's not doable in JS in your opinion, unless maybe with regex?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that I think you're misunderstanding the meaning of that operator. Please look at @YTowOnt9's answer as it is what I would have suggested. If you want something else, please clarify by posting a working example (hint: try using http://jsfiddle.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `vars` are storing selectors, you can separate them by a comma to form a selector which matches either selector:

```
var afoo = 'a.foo';
var abar = 'div.bar ul';

var either = afoo + ', ' + abar;
```

Comment: var var1= ':not(.sc-col)';
        var var2= $('.clearfix-col');
        var row_end = var1 , var2; but that didn't work

Comment: @Nirs That `var2` isn't a selector, it is a jQuery object. Try just `var var2 = '.clearfix0col';`

Comment: yes i tried this too unfortunately. Looks like I will have to find a workaround, thanks for the help.